# Setting a GitHub pages site from a Jekyll-generated page

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I cannot setup a new Jekyll-based GitHub pages site based on the tutorials I've read. Here is the full list of steps I took:

1. Ran `jekyll new jek_test`. This created a new dir.
2. Used GitHub desktop to create a git repository in that dir, then pushed it to a new git repository, [jek_test](https://github.com/gadial/jek_test).
3. In the project settings *GitHub Pages* panel, I choose *master branch* as source.

So far this had no effect I could see. Navigating to https://gadial.github.io/jek_test/ yielded a 404 error.

4. I added the following two lines to the projects Gemfile:

`source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins`

Now, after pushing to GitHub, the https://gadial.github.io/jek_test/ link is working, but the page loaded is obviously incorrect; the CSS is not loaded, the links are wrong, etc.

I guess I am missing several crucial steps, but all the tutorials I've found either go "simply push it and everything will be ok", or seem to assume I am not using a Gem-based theme, meaning all the layouts, css files etc. are explicitly stored in the _layouts directories etc.

Am I going about this the right way? What is the simplest method to get a Jekyll-generated site up and running on GitHub pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `minima` which is the default so, that's not the issue but, if you have a look at your [about.md](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gadial/jek_test/master/about.md) you'll see that it is looking for a layout called page. You currently don't have a `_layouts` folder

Try creating a folder called `_layouts` and create a layout in that called `page.html` with however you want it to display the contents of all files with `layout : page`

The default `page.html` can be found [here.](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_layouts/page.html)

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly, the _layouts folder should be located inside the minima Gem (Which should be supported by GitHub pages). If I try to `bundle exec jekyll serve` the site locally, it succeeds, even without the _layouts folder. That said, I will try your suggestion if there is no "better" way of doing this.

Comment: No you're right. I looked into it, it should work without the `_layouts` folder per the latest documentation. Maybe have a look [at this?](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll) asks you to change [your Gemfile](https://github.com/gadial/jek_test/blob/master/Gemfile) as suggested in its comments itself.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the Jekyll gem as suggested in the comments, and added the github-pages gem (which I added before, see step 4), ran `bundle update` and pushed to github. I don't see any effect.

Comment: So, I had a look at the console output when loading the website. These are the error messages that come : "GET https://gadial.github.io/assets/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
gadial.github.io/:61 GET https://gadial.github.io/assets/minima-social-icons.svg net::ERR_ABORTED 404" 
It's looking for a css file under `gadial.github.io`, when it should actually be looking under `gadial.github.io/jek_test`, try setting the `baseurl` or `url` in your `_config.yml` to `https://gadial.github.io/jek_test`

Comment: I edited your page using chrome dev tools to change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/main.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jek_test/assets/main.css">`, seems to work now.

Comment: This is great, but the questions remains - what did I do wrong? Bad links indicate I didn't modify some critical file - which file? Should I have known about it from the tutorials I tried to follow or is this something new stemming from the relatively new Gemfile-theme approach?

Comment: I'm not sure you did anything wrong, just that by default github-pages looks for the `assets` under `your-name.github.io/` whereas you're actually hosting your site at `your-name.github.io/repo-name/` , changing this variable points it to the right source for the `assets`

Comment: Ok, now I understand. You are correct - my error was simply not setting the baseurl setting in _config.yml. Thank you!

Comment: @isstiaung I just wanted you to know that I had the same issue and was Googling all over for a solution, and your suggestion about changing the `baseurl` was what worked for me. If you put that part in your actual answer it may get more visibility and help others like me 

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change url to "https://gadial.github.io" and baseurl to "/jek_test".

If this two attributes are not set up properly, Jekyll won't know where to look for your resources.